# `hash` in script doesn't run properly with Process

Tags: java, bash, process

I have a script with the following line:

`hash git >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "Git is not installed"; exit 2; }`

asserting `git` is installed and, if not, exiting. I want to run it with Java:

`new ProcessBuilder("script.sh", "0").start().waitFor()`

The process always exits because `git` isn't being found, even though it runs perfectly fine in bash (because it is installed).

EDIT: same with `command -v` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` (all combinations)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way java calls system subprocesses, but are you sure the `PATH` variable is sourced in the newly created context ? Maybe try `bash script.sh` ?

Comment: @Aserre I have also tried: `new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", ...)`. Even when I set `PATH` in `Process.getR().exec(c, env)`, it doesn't work. I think the problem is `hash`, because `sleep 100` before it runs fine and after that doesn't.

Comment: @Aserre a full `PATH` (like in `echo $PATH`) worked! Make this an answer so that I can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `$PATH` variable is not sourced in the new context created by the `ProcessBuilder` method.

As your script executes fine and doesn't throw an error, even if it shows an unexpected result, it seems that `hash` is recognized, but that your call doesn't know where to look for the `git` executable

Try rewritting your script using the full path to the function for java to be able to find the executables, i.e. `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: Take the output of `echo $PATH` and use it in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, new String[] {  <echo> })`.